# How small can we make an integer-valued sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, integers

If we create Fibonacci-like sequences of the form:

$$x_n = c_1 x_{n-1} + c_2 x_{n-2} + c_3 x_{n-3} + \dots + c_m x_{n-m} \tag{1}$$

We can study the growth rate of such sequences.  For example, the Fibonacci sequence itself is of the form:

$$x_n = c_1 x_{n-1} + c_2 x_{n-2}$$

Of course, with $c_1=1$ and $c_2=1$.  The Fibonacci sequence itself has the form:

$$\frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\varphi - \psi}$$

It is easy to see that this is dominated by the term $\varphi^n$, since $\varphi \approx 1.6$ and $\psi \approx -0.6$.

I'm looking to create integer-valued sequences of the form $(1)$, but I want to minimize the growth rate.  In essence, for given $m$, I'm attempting to minimize $f(n)$ with $x_n \in O(f(n))$.

So my question is, what is the smallest $f(n)$ possible, for a given $m$?  In other words, how slowly can we make equation $(1)$ grow, given $m$?

We can assume the coefficients are integer-valued.

Comment: Have you seen derivations of $F_n=\frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\varphi - \psi}$?  Have you tried looking at how they can help you here?

Comment: If you are defining $\psi = \frac1\varphi$, then the formula for the Fibonacci numbers should be $$F(n)=\frac{\varphi^n - (-\psi)^n}{\varphi - (-\psi)}.$$

Comment: @SimpleArt:  Yes, I've read (part of) Wilf's Generatingfunctionology some time ago.  That would give me $f(n)$ for a particular $m$, but what I'm really after is the growth rate of $f(n)$ as $m$ increases.  I don't know how to find _this_ growth rate.

Comment: @Théophile:  Sorry, I corrected the entry for $\psi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've seen this particular derivation of the closed form for the Fibonacci numbers, you will notice that

$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n\implies\varphi^2=\varphi+1,\quad\psi^2=\psi+1$$

Indeed, it is easy enough to see that if

$$a_{n+m}=c_1a_{n+m-1}+c_2a_{n+m-2}+\dots+c_ma_n$$

$$\implies \phi_k^m=c_1\phi_k^{m-1}+c_2\phi_k^{m-2}+\dots+c_{m-1}\phi_k+c_m$$

So simply find the largest $\phi_k$ that satisfies the above polynomial of degree $m$.  Simple root finding algorithms should suffice.  (Also note of a constant in front, which can be found by putting in a few points (larger numbers work better for these points).  Then,

$$a_n\approx C_k\phi_k^n$$

for some constant $C_k$.  The exact form should be given by

$$a_n=C_1\phi_1^n+C_2\phi_2^n+C_3\phi_3^n+\dots+C_k\phi_k^n$$

Comment: Note $\phi_i$ may be complex.